# Retrieve current location in javascript using ng-map/angularjs-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

How do I retrieve my current location in javascript using the angularjs-google-maps api by allenhwkim?

Currently I am able to access my current location through the html code

```
<marker animation="DROP" position="current-location"></marker>
```

however I wish to implement a current location button which will let me center the map to my current location whenever I am away from my current location itself.

html:

```
<input type="submit" Value="currentLocation" ng-click ="currentLocation()"/>
```

js:

```
$scope.currentLocation = function(){
        //how do i get current location?
};
```

thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.position));                  
            }, 
            function(error) {                    
                alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
            }, options);
```

Comment: It's also worth checking that the browser supports geolocation first by null checking navigator.geolocation.  See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp